# kendo extract data to pdf file doesn't work asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, data-extraction

I have implemented the extraction option of kendo grid to a PDF file, I found the solution in kendo forum on the following:

```
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/pdf-export
```

I have folow the instruction i installed the **pako.min.js** script and i have updated my kendo version : i install **the Q1 2015**
Even that when i extract data from my kendo grid i got a  screen print that containt just the data of the first kendo page  there is my kendo grid code :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GesTim.WebApp.Areas.DataManagement.ViewModels.AgencyViewModels>().Name("Agencies").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:500px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd").Error("error"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Get", "xxxxx"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "xxxx"))
        .ServerOperation(true)
    )

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator(""))).Hidden(true).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.xxx).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").ShowOperators(false)));
        columns.Bound(c => c.xxxx).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").ShowOperators(false)));

        columns.Command(command =>
        {
                command.Custom("Details").SendDataKeys(true).Click("showDetails").Text(" ");
                command.Custom("Edit").SendDataKeys(true).Click("Editer").Text(" ");
                command.Custom("Delete").Text(" ").Click("confirmRemove");
        }).Width("150px");
    })

            .Events(e => e.DataBound("onRowBound"))
            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
      {
              toolbar.Custom().Text("Ajouter xxx").Action("Create", "xxx", new { area = "DataManagement" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btn-ajouter" });
          toolbar.Excel().Text("Exporter au format Excel");
          **toolbar.Pdf();**
      })

               .Excel(excel => excel
                       .AllPages(true)
                       .FileName("Liste des xxx.xlsx")
                            .Filterable(true)
                            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "xxx"))
                        )
        **.Pdf(pdf => pdf
            .AllPages()
                    .FileName("Liste des xxx.pdf")
                    .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Pdf_Export_Save", "xxx"))
                      )**

                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                    .PageSizes(true)
                .ButtonCount(10))


        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))

)
```

th result of my implementation is  , i got a file with data but in the kedno grid like that: [image]
 Is ther any thing missed ?? please help

Comment: Just to clarify.  Did you get a pdf file but it was empty?

Comment: @gardarvalur , i get a pdf file which is not empty : my pdf file is the image that i put on my question

Comment: Oh I see.  I honestly think this is how it comes out of the package from Telerik.

Comment: @gardarvalur but the demos of telerik show an ordianr  pdf file , youdidn't find anything wrong ith my code içs that right??

Comment: I see your dilemma.  The http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export demo page clearly shows you export the content only.  I tried this on my end and I got the same result as you (with header of grid and all).  Your code seems to be fine.

Comment: @gardarvalur thanks for your help it seems that this is an issue of kendo that they must fix it , i wil see with them hopefully it will end with a solution fastly

Comment: OlfaD if you get a response from Telerik I would really appreciate if you could answer your own question with an appropriate answer.  I need to fix thiss too in my own project  ;)

Comment: @gardarvalur ok i will :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75193/discussion-between-olfad-and-gardarvalur).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the kendo technical support and they told me that me solution of my problem was to use a style for extract pdf files like bellow:

```
 <style>
        /*
                Use the DejaVu Sans font for display and embedding in the PDF file.
                The standard PDF fonts have no support for Unicode characters.
            */
        .k-grid {
            font-family: "DejaVu Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
        }

        /* Hide the Grid header and pager during export */
        .k-pdf-export .k-grid-toolbar,
        .k-pdf-export .k-pager-wrap,
        .k-pdf-export a.k-button.k-button-icontext,
        .k-pdf-export .k-filter-row,
        .k-pdf-export .k-grouping-header,
        .k-pdf-export .k-grid tr td:last-child {
            display: none !important;
        }

    </style>
```

Comment: Could you post the complete view and controller action, please? I'm having a similar issue and I've included the style, but with no luck. Thanks a lot.